# How to get the position of the nth nonblank cell of a column in excel?

Tags: excel

I would like to get the position of the nth (e.g. the third) nonblank cell in a range (e.g. A1:A10) in excel. Cells can contain strings, too, not only numbers. Could anybody help me in? Thank you!

Comment: What is the difficulties you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** put the *array formula*:

```
= MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(A:A), 0)
```

In **B2** put the *array formula*:

```
= MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDIRECT("A" & B1+1 & ":A9999")), 0)+B1
```

and copy down.

**B1** will point to the first non-blank, **B2** will point to the second non-blank, etc.

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I should use MS Office 2003, where "= MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(A:A), 0)" doesn't work. If I apply explicit bounds, the formula is active. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Roloka  I am not familiar with ***Excel 200*** ??

Comment: @Roloka  For really old versions of Excel, use something like:  `= MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(A1:A9999), 0)`